# How to write multiple if conditions

Tags: c++

I have two variables `A` and `B` and I want to write a code where if one of the two variables is equal to

```
151 or 156 or 720
```

and the other is not equal to one of these numbers then a third variable `C = 0` is equal to one.

So for example

```
1) if A = 151 and B = 700 then C = 1 
2) if A = 151 and B = 720 then C = 0
3) if A = 140 and B = 700 then C = 0
```

This is the code

```
int A = 0
cin >> A;
int B = 0
cin >> B;
int C=0;
int DECKlist[3] = {151,156,720}
for(int d=0; d<3;d++){
      if(A== DECKlist[d]){
           for(int w=0; w<3;w++){
                if(B==DECKlist[w]) C=0;
                 else C=1;
            }
       }
       if(B== DECKlist[d]){
           for(int w=0; w<3;w++){
                if(A==DECKlist[w]) C=0;
                 else C=1;
            }
       }
}
```

Is this OK? There are other better ways of doing it?

Comment: `if(A== DECKlist[0] && B == DECKlist[1]){//value of C appropriate} else{// Other value }`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an exclusive OR, XOR. There is no logical XOR in C++, but you can use the bit-wise XOR for your case and exploit the fact that the result of a logical operator is a `bool` which will map to 0 or 1:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int A, B, C;

    std::cin >> A;
    std::cin >> B;

    A = (A == 151 || A == 156 || A == 720);
    B = (B == 151 || B == 156 || B == 720);

    C = A ^ B;

    std::cout << C << std::endl;
}
```

I've used a simple expression here to check whether a number is one of three supplied numbers. For larger sets of numbers to check against, you could use a, well, `std::set`.

Comment: @Yakk: Never seen it that way. In this case, it works (and is even clearer than `^`), but it doesn't apply to more general truth cases. There is no orthogonality between `A && B`, `A || B` and `A != B` (used as XOR) when A and B are integers where any value except `0` is a true value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard algorithms. For example you could use standard algoritnm `std::binary_search` along with bitwise XOR operator because array `DECKlist` is sorted

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

int DECKlist[] = { 151, 156, 720 };

//...

if ( std::binary_search( std::begin( DECKlist ), std::end( DECKlist ), A ) ^
     std::binary_search( std::begin( DECKlist ), std::end( DECKlist ), B ) )
{
   C = 1;
}
```

In this case you may add new values in the array and the approach will work as usual correctly. It does not depend on "magic numbers" and their quntity.:)

Comment: of course it must be `B` in the second `binary_search()`; besides there is no 'logical XOR', look at the comment in M.Oehm's answer

Comment: @Ingo Leonhardt Thanks. It was a typo as the result of copy and paste of the first expression.:)

Comment: `!=` is logical xor, instead of bitwise `^`?  Not sure which is clearer.

Comment: @Yakk Yes there can be used != instead of bitwise ^. But in any case it is better to use an array of values and the algorithm. In this case the code will be flexible.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
int c=0;
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    if(A == DECKlist[i]) c++;
    if(B == DECKlist[i]) c++;
}
c = c%2;
```

Basically, count the number of matches, then make it zero if it was 2.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is hide the searching code.  Here is a bit of C++ that will search an array (or any other container) linearly for if a given value is there.  It uses a two C++11 features: `std::begin` and `std::end`, and `auto` typed variables:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

template<class Array, class T>
bool find_in( Array const& arr, T const& t ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  const auto b = begin(arr);
  const auto e = end(arr);
  const auto it = std::find( b, e, t ); // search the range for t
  return !(e != it);
}
```

`find_in` is passed an array and a value, and returns true if that value is in the array.

We then use the same preamble.  I avoid `using namespace std;` because it is a bad habit -- just name things with `std::` or import individual symbols within a function scope.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int A = 0
  std::cin >> A;
  int B = 0
  std::cin >> B;
  int C=0;
  int DECKlist[3] = {151,156,720};
  bool A_in_list = find_in(DECKlist, A);
  bool B_in_list = find_in(DECKlist, B);
  if (A_in_list != B_in_list)
    C = 1;
  std::cout << C << "\n";
}
```

The searching code, because I put it in a helper function, is really clean in the "core" logic of the program.

As we want to know when one is in the list, but not the other, we just compare the results using `!=`.